# Item will not reflect with latest source

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

i am face one problem regarding Bind data to the ItemsControl. From the code behind add item in to the source but that will not reflect on ItemsControl, please correct me where i am do wrong 
my code sample as below

```
<UserControl x:Class="DragDropListbox.SilverlightControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="MyDT">
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Content="Add" Height="23" x:Name="btnadd" Width="75" Margin="10,0" Click="btnadd_Click" />
            <Button Content="Delete" Height="23" x:Name="btndelete" Width="75" Click="btndelete_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stk" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ic1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllEmp,Mode=OneWay}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDT}">
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Cs File Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DragDropListbox
{
    public partial class SilverlightControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public SilverlightControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stk.DataContext = new Emps() { AllEmp = new List<emp>() { new emp() { Name = "Name - 0" } } };
        }

        private void btnadd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var k = stk.DataContext as Emps;
            k.AllEmp.Add(new emp() { Name = string.Format("Name - {0}", k.AllEmp.Count) });
        }

        private void btndelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var k = stk.DataContext as Emps;
            if (k.AllEmp.Count > 0)
            {
                k.AllEmp.Remove(k.AllEmp[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Emps : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<emp> _AllEmp;

        public List<emp> AllEmp
        {
            get { return _AllEmp; }
            set
            {
                _AllEmp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllEmp");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler ph = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (ph != null)
            {
                ph(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }

    public class emp
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your *AllEmp* collection an **[ObservableCollection<emp>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/ms668604.aspx)** instead of a List<emp>.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pragmateek, after your answer i am seen the differance between list and ObservableCollection and got the answer why list is not working for me